# Regex Match Phrase with Different Symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have here a phrase `AAC Barcode Description` that regex should match.

The problem is sometimes I have underscore, symbols etc...
like

- AAC Barcode + Descriptions
- AAC Barcode + Description
- AAC Barcode & Descriptions
- AAC Barcode and Description

**REGEX**

```
\b\w*AAC Barcode Description\w*\b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\w*AAC Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)Description\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/faPkle/1). Note that word boundaries are redundant in this case when used with `\w*`s. If you want to match this string is a whole word, you need to remove `\w*`s and keep `\b`s:

```
\bAAC Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)Description\b
```

*Details*:

- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `AAC Barcode`  - a fixed string
- `(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)` - a non-capturing group matching either `and` enclosed with one or more whitespaces or one or more non-word chars
- `Description` - a fixed string
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why is this not returning? https://jsfiddle.net/n8cgpr7u/2/

Comment: @Joseph Yes, use a regex literal, `/\w*AAC Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)Description\w*/`, see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yu48s9xc/).

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Can we cater regardless of uppercase/lowercase?

Comment: @Joseph Certainly, `/\w*AAC Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)Description\w*/i`. Multiple occurrences: ``/\w*AAC Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|\W+)Description\w*/gi``

Comment: @Joseph You have a non-matching string, here is a matching one - https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/q9jgLmzw/

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Please check this again. https://regex101.com/r/0WAPU7/1
Can we check if it just contains AAC Barcode Description. We would match it? right now I added some with _ and -. It doesn't match anymore.

Comment: @Joseph Then use `\w*AAC[\W_]+Barcode(?:\s+and\s+|[\W_]+)Description\w*`, see https://regex101.com/r/0WAPU7/2